# Record twice update alternative

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

I have this method in a controller class that updates the product on a custom object (Contract Modification) based on what the user selects in the UI.
In this object i have a Section 'Validations' where i am showing custom labels in case they are triggered. I have a custom apex validation rule (in another class) that checks if the Move Date < Product's Valid Date.

The issue is, after i update the product through the LWC Component, the product is changed but the custom label does not dissapear even though the condition for the error is not met, because for some reason, in the debug logs i still have the old product. If i update the conMod twice through the controller method, then the Product's Valid Date updates for the new product and the custom label dissapears as expected.

Are there any alternatives for double updating a record?

Note: I am far for reaching any governor limits with this second update: 4/150

Controller Method (called in LWC.js handleSubmit button):

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static ProductUpdateResponse updateSelectedProductOnConMod(
            String billingModeFromFilter,
            String categoryTypeFromFilter,
            Id conModId,
            String gridFromFilter,
            Id parentId,
            String powerCapacityFromFilter,
            Id selectedProductId,
            String smartMeterStatusFromFilter,
            String voltageLevelPODFromFilter
    ) {
        //Prepare response variable
        ProductUpdateResponse response = new ProductUpdateResponse();

        //Get the Product from Database
        Product2 productDetails = EL_Product2_Sel.queryProductsFromIds(new Set<Id>{
                selectedProductId
        })[0];

        //Check if Ids are not missing
        if (!String.isEmpty(selectedProductId) && !String.isEmpty(conModId)) {
            //Try-Catch
            try {
                //Prepare Con Mod record to update
                EL_Contract_Modification__c conMod = new EL_Contract_Modification__c();
                conMod.Id = conModId;

                //Populate Products Ids
                if (!String.isEmpty(parentId)) {
                    conMod.EL_Option__c = selectedProductId;
                    conMod.EL_Main_Product__c = parentId;
                } else {
                    conMod.EL_Option__c = null; // MP2-5027
                    conMod.EL_Main_Product__c = selectedProductId;
                }

                //Update other necessary fields on Con Mod
                conMod.EL_Customer_Group__c = productDetails.EL_Customer_Group__c;
                conMod.EL_Supplier__c = productDetails.EL_Supplier__c;
                conMod.EL_Product_Category__c = productDetails.EL_Product_Category__c;
                conMod.EL_Meter_Type__c = productDetails.EL_Meter_Type__c;
                conMod.EL_Commodity_Type__c = productDetails.EL_Commodity_Type__c;
                conMod.EL_Service_Component__c = productDetails.EL_Service_Component__c;
                conMod.EL_Material__c = productDetails.EL_Material__c;

                //Billing Mode
                if (billingModeFromFilter != null && !String.isEmpty(billingModeFromFilter)) {
                    conMod.EL_Billing_Mode__c = billingModeFromFilter;
                }

                //Smart Meter Status
                if (smartMeterStatusFromFilter != null && !String.isEmpty(smartMeterStatusFromFilter)) {
                    conMod.EL_Smart_Meter_Status__c = smartMeterStatusFromFilter;
                }

                //Power Capacity
                if (powerCapacityFromFilter != null && !String.isEmpty(powerCapacityFromFilter)) {
                    conMod.EL_TF_Power_Capacity__c = powerCapacityFromFilter;
                }

                //Category Type
                if (categoryTypeFromFilter != null && !String.isEmpty(categoryTypeFromFilter)) {
                    conMod.EL_Category_Type__c = categoryTypeFromFilter;
                }

                //Grid
                if (gridFromFilter != null && !String.isEmpty(gridFromFilter)) {
                    conMod.EL_Grid__c = gridFromFilter;
                }

                //Voltage Level from POD
                if (voltageLevelPODFromFilter != null && !String.isEmpty(voltageLevelPODFromFilter)) {
                    conMod.EL_Voltage_Level_POD__c = voltageLevelPODFromFilter;
                }
                
                //Update the Con Mod
                update conMod;
                
                //Success true
                response.isSuccess = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                response.isSuccess = false;
                response.errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                LOG_LogMessageUtility.logMessage(e, 'EL_Product_Selection_Controller', 'EL_Product_Selection_Controller.updateSelectedProductOnConMod', e.getMessage(), true);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Custom Label method from another class (called on BeforeUpdate):

```
protected void validateMoveDateWithProductValidity(List<String> errors) {

        //In order to access related Product's fields, get the enriched version of CM
        EL_Contract_Modification__c enrichedConMod = contractModificationXDomSel.enrichedConModMap.get(conMod.Id);

        //MP2-5140 - Decide the logic for the Move Date based on the CM Record Type
        Date contractModificationMoveDate;
        if (conMod.RecordTypeId == UTL_SF.getRecordTypeByName(EL_CST.CONTRACT_MODIFICATION_RECORDTYPE_PRODUCT_UPDATE, 'EL_Contract_Modification__c').Id) {
            contractModificationMoveDate = conMod.EL_Optional_Product_Start_Date__c;
        } else if (conMod.RecordTypeId == UTL_SF.getRecordTypeByName(EL_CST.CONTRACT_MODIFICATION_RECORDTYPE_BEGINNING_OF_SUPPLY, 'EL_Contract_Modification__c').Id
                || conMod.RecordTypeId == UTL_SF.getRecordTypeByName(EL_CST.CONTRACT_MODIFICATION_RECORDTYPE_END_OF_SUPPLY, 'EL_Contract_Modification__c').Id) {
            contractModificationMoveDate = conMod.EL_Move_Date__c;
        }

        //MP2-5140 - Decide the logic for the Product Valid From and Valid Until based on the CM Option field (If the product is a parent or a child product)
        Date productValidFrom;
        Date productValidUntil;
        if (conMod.EL_Option__c == null) {
            productValidFrom = enrichedConMod.EL_Main_Product__r.EL_Valid_From__c;
            productValidUntil = enrichedConMod.EL_Main_Product__r.EL_Valid_Until__c;


        } else {
            productValidFrom = enrichedConMod.EL_Option__r.EL_Valid_From__c;
            productValidUntil = enrichedConMod.EL_Option__r.EL_Valid_Until__c;
        }
        //Check whether the Contract Modification's Move Date is null or outside the valid interval for the related Product
        if (contractModificationMoveDate != null && productValidFrom != null
                && (productValidUntil != null && (contractModificationMoveDate < productValidFrom || contractModificationMoveDate > productValidUntil))
                || (productValidUntil == null && contractModificationMoveDate < productValidFrom)
        )

        {
            
            //Add the error to the display list
            errors.add(Label.EL_Invalid_CM_Product_Move_Date);
            
        }
    }
```

Fix:
In the js, i used updateRecords to update the Product's Valid Dates on the record.

```
handleProductSubmit(event){
        //Enable the loading
        this.calloutLoading = true;

        //Update the Contract Modification's Product
        updateSelectedProductOnConMod({
            billingModeFromFilter: this.billingModeValue,
            categoryTypeFromFilter: this.categoryTypeValue,
            conModId: this.recordId,
            gridFromFilter: this.gridValue,
            parentId: this.selectedProduct.parentId,
            powerCapacityFromFilter: this.powerCapacityValue,
            selectedProductId: this.selectedProduct.id,
            smartMeterStatusFromFilter: this.smartMeterStatusValue,
            voltageLevelPODFromFilter: this.voltageLevelPODValue
        })
        .then(result => {
            if(result.isSuccess){
                const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: this.label.successTitle,
                    message: this.label.successMessage,
                    variant: 'success',
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(evt);

                // Update the record
                const fields = {
                Id: this.recordId
                    }
                };
                const recordInput = { fields };
                updateRecord(recordInput).then(() => {
                // Notify that the record has changed
                getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
                }).catch(updateError => {
                   console.error('Error updating record', updateError);
                });

            }
            else {
                const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: this.label.errorTitle,
                    message: result.errorMessage,
                    variant: 'error',
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.calloutLoading = false
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does your product update response include the updated product details? (You didn't include this object in your code snippet.) How is the LWC getting the updated product details?

Comment: Artur, make sure you put the answer is the answer box (below). You can self-answer, and even accept your own answer. Do not use `[Solved]` to indicate it is solved; you can use the ✅ next to the answer once you've added it to indicate it is the solution.